# How to parse data from Outlook mails to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook

I receive lot of emails with almost similar content from the two email addresses to my Outlook email account. I want to extract content from these emails and send it to an Excel spreadsheet in a way that "Item" field from the email would parse into a column named Item. The mail body has these three main headings - Item, Description and Vendor. Process should be automated and it would be great if I don’t have to run some Macro for it. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible but quite complex. I doubt anyone here would be likely to help you with some code without you showing that you have attempted something yourself first.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Save e-mail as text. Create a rule that matches your incoming e-mail and then use a script: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/code-samples/save-email-message-text-file/

Comment: Can you provide the sample of the Item/Description/Vendor fields as they are appear in bodies of your emails?

Comment: @LunaMezza, thanks, that's what I'm thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Outlook account on an Exchange Server?
If so you can use the free Microsoft Add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010) for extracting mails from your Exchange account directly into Excel. You will have to define some steps to get the data you want. It's like a makro, although easier to learn.

Have a look on the Microsoft [Support](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Connect-to-Exchange-Power-Query-33538dbe-04bc-4d62-8560-20f031666414?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) Website.

This [Blog post](http://www.affirmaconsulting.com/take-action-on-your-e-mail-in-2016-using-power-query/) shows some possibilities as well.